# map of map as Bean injection in springboot configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot

i usually use springboot to inject Beans and use patterns like

in a application.properties file

```
platform.accounts.acbot71.name=acbot71
platform.accounts.acbot71.secret=secret1
platform.accounts.acbot72.name=acbot72
platform.accounts.acbot72.secret=secret2
```

in a springboot configuration file

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "platform.accounts")
@Bean
public Map<String, PlatformAccount> platformAccounts() {
    return new TreeMap<>();
}
```

with PlatformAccount as a pojo with classic getters and setters

```
String name;
String email;
```

All is ok. But now, i'd like to do an advanced configuration with 'inner' map
for each value of the existing map.
I'd like to build an application properties like..

```
platform.accounts.acbot71.name=acbot71
platform.accounts.acbot71.secret=secret1
platform.accounts.acbot71.subaccount1.name=sub1
platform.accounts.acbot71.subaccount1.secret=secret1
platform.accounts.acbot71.subaccount2.name=sub2
platform.accounts.acbot71.subaccount2.secret=secret2
platform.accounts.acbot72.name=acbot72
platform.accounts.acbot72.secret=secret2
platform.accounts.acbot72.subaccount1.name=sub1
platform.accounts.acbot72.subaccount1.secret=secret1
```

Purpose is to inject a second map into each object of type PlatformAccount
(i.e. the value of the first map)

How can i do that ?
any code as example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in application.yml instead, and tweak the properties to have a subAccounts map.

```yaml
platform:
  accounts:
    acbot71:
      name: acbot71
      secret: secret1
      subAccounts:
        subaccount1:
          name: sub1
          secret: secret1
        subaccount2:
          name: sub2
          secret: secret2
    acbot72:
      name: acbot72
      secret: secret2
      subAccounts:
        subaccount1:
          name: sub1
          secret: secret1
```

I guess it would look like this in application.properties...

```
platform.accounts.acbot71.name=acbot71
platform.accounts.acbot71.secret=secret1
platform.accounts.acbot71.subAccounts.subaccount1.name=sub1
platform.accounts.acbot71.subAccounts.subaccount1.secret=secret1
platform.accounts.acbot71.subAccounts.subaccount2.name=sub2
platform.accounts.acbot71.subAccounts.subaccount2.secret=secret2
platform.accounts.acbot72.name=acbot72
platform.accounts.acbot72.secret=secret2
platform.accounts.acbot72.subAccounts.subaccount1.name=sub1
platform.accounts.acbot72.subAccounts.subaccount1.secret=secret1
```

And your PlatformAccount class could look like this.

```java
public class PlatformAccount {
    private String name;
    private String secret;
    private Map<String, PlatformAccount> subAccounts;
}
```

I've never tried anything like this, Spring might freak out about the nested identical class. If it does, you would have to make a SubAccount config class.